# what's the meaning of -bash PHPUnit command not found

Tags: php, bash, terminal, pear, yii

i have pear's phpunit installed (see image)

I have that path in the include path (see image below) in php.ini. Note, other pear installations have worked with this include path, so I know there's nothing wrong with that path per see.

Yet, when I'm trying to do a an example functional test with Yii , I move into the directory protected/tests/  and run this code (provided by a book I'm learning)

```
 % cd protected/tests/ 
    % phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
```

I get told

```
-bash: phpunit: command not found
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: directory]

[image: path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your shell cannot find the `phpunit` command. Specify the full path to the command.

```
/some/path/here/phpunit ....php
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the command `phpunit` couldn't be found. Are you trying to run a PHP file? In that case, write:

```
php phpfile.php
```

Otherwise, specify the full path to the command.

Comment: maybe the command isn't in that path, but I don't know what I did wrong.